# Use semver package to convert ^4.2.3 to 4.2.3

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

Using the semver NPM package
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver

is there a way to convert a package version like so `^4.2.3`, to one that is without the `^`? I just need to do string manipulation to remove any preceding characters that are not numbers, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, the answer is in the docs, of course:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver

it says:

```
semver.clean('  =v1.2.3   ') // '1.2.3'
```