# Parse array written to stdout from `npm view x dependencies`

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run the command

```
$ npm view JSONStream@^1.3.1 dependencies --json
```

I get:

```
[
  {
    "jsonparse": "^1.2.0",
    "through": ">=2.2.7 <3"
  },
  {
    "jsonparse": "^1.2.0",
    "through": ">=2.2.7 <3"
  }
]
```

my question is, what does each element in the array represent? I am guessing it represents a snapshot of the dependencies for each published version of JSONStream. However, the problem is I don't know which version each element is for! I would have thought it would have looked like this instead:

```
{
 "2.3.5": {
    "jsonparse": "^1.2.0",
    "through": ">=2.2.7 <3"
  },
  "2.3.6":{
    "jsonparse": "^1.2.0",
    "through": ">=2.2.7 <3"
  }
}
```

does anyone know how to figure out what each element in the array represents?

Comment: Uh, when I run the command I just get `{
  "jsonparse": "^1.2.0",
  "through": ">=2.2.7 <3"
}`. What version of `npm` are you using? I'm on 5.6.0

Comment: Yeah I am on npm v5.6.0 too, weird, are you sure you use the --json flag?

Comment: Yep. If I run without `--json`, I just get a colorized version of the same output in my comment.

Comment: check this out: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xdeuleupa9hm3s/Screenshot%202018-01-19%2013.50.50.png?dl=0

Comment: maybe it's the `^` symbol that causes that, did you use that in your command?

Comment: Here's mine since you seem not to believe me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/48kIp.png

Comment: ah you are on Windows, can you try using a bash shell (git bash, perhaps) and run the same command?

Comment: fyi, this might be useful info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348948/use-semver-package-to-convert-4-2-3-to-4-2-3/48350085

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting the same output.

Comment: So you got the same output when using the bash terminal instead of the windows terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `npm view JSONStream@^1.3.1 version --json` to determine the respective version for each entry:

```
[
  "1.3.1",
  "1.3.2"
]
```

Protip, the argument after the package name is a field from the `package.json`. You can also omit the argument to see the entire metadata for each version.

Comment: thanks good call, I got rid of the caret `^` using `require('semver').clean()`, but yeah

Comment: if you like the semver.clean() question/answer linked in the comments to the OP, let me know